# How to tell if a particle has entered a region?

Tags: geometry, physics

I'm working in python but this is really more of an algorithmic question. Imagine I have four particles connected by springs to form a soft-bodied polygon. I want to figure out when and where a fifth particle collides with this object so I can have them bounce off of each other. What is the best way to detect if a particle has entered a region?

Answer (score 2):

Given that your polygon is always formed by 4 points, you don't need to use a general case point/polygon intersection algorithm, you can just split your parallelogram in two triangles and do the [point inside triangle](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html) test with the 5th point. If the point is inside one of the triangles, then the particle has entered the region.